# How can I get a JTextArea to consume its key events?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, focus, jtextarea

I have a GUI window with several components. Some of them are buttons to which I added keyboard shortcuts. For example, a certain button can be triggered by pressing "a" anywhere in the window. One of the components in a JTextArea. Now, when the focus is in the textarea, and the user types, e.g., "aha" into the JTextArea, the button is triggered twice (in addition to the text "aha" being added to the text area). How can I turn this off? I want the JTextArea to consume the "a" event, so that it does not also trigger the button.

What I want: if an "a" is typed anywhere in the window *except* in the JTextArea, I want my button to be triggered. But I don't want the button to be triggered while the JTextArea is in focus and the user is typing into the JTextArea.

What I already tried: I tried adding a KeyListener to the JTextArea, which intercepts and consumes any key that is typed. But it had the opposite effect: the button is still triggered, but the letter is not added to the JTextArea.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

// Create a simple GUI window                                                   
public class Gui
{
    private static void createWindow()
    {
        // Create a frame.                                                      
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple");

        // Add a                                                                

        // Add a text area.                                                     
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
        textarea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(textarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Add a button.                                                        
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Button");
        button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.get\
KeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "key");
        Action action = new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Action!");
                    button.doClick();
                }

            };
        button.getActionMap().put("key", action);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        createWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: `JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(); textarea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));` better to size a text area by specifying the [number of rows & columns in the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#<init>(int,int)). This turns guesswork into design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JTextArea listens for `keyTyped` events. You are adding a binding for `keyPressed`.

If you instead create the binding for `keyTyped` event then the text area will handle the event:

```
//button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "key");
button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("typed a"), "key");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant! I confirm that this works for the "a" key. But I can't figure out the string representation for some of the other keys I am using, such as the "home" key. E.g., "typed home" doesn't seem to be it. The documentation here: (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(java.lang.String)) says that I must use a single Unicode character after "typed", but as far as I know, there is no Unicode character representing the "home" key, nor many others such as PgUp. Are there symbolic macros analogous to the VK macros for keyTyped events?

Comment: The "typed" is for characters that can be typed into a text component. It will not work for other keys. For other key bindings you would do what you did with your original code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again! I noticed that for keys such as arrow keys, home, and so on, using them in the text area did not trigger my buttons even with my original code. This must be because the text area treats these keys as keyPressed events, and the rest as keyTyped. Confusing, but makes some sense. Thanks for your helpful answers.

Comment: See: [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a little app that displays the bindings for each Swing component.